# Modify an UpdatePanel by calling server-side code from client code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, treeview, updatepanel

It's possible that there's no way to do this, but I figure I would ask. I'm relatively new to asp.net, having played with it for about a week now. What I have right now is a page that calls a web service, polls it until it's done (with progress displayed in an UpdatePanel), then hides the progress text and instead displays the result (a recursive list of files with some metadata) by creating a TreeView and adding it to the UpdatePanel. What I would like is for clicking a node in the TreeView to update a second UpdatePanel with extended information (obtained server-side) about the node that was just clicked on. I don't see any way to call a codebehind function by clicking a TreeNode, but I *can* call Javascript code by setting the node's NavigateUrl to "javascript:function([the full path of the node])".

At this point, though, I'm kind of stumped. StackOverflow is full of correctly-answered questions about how to call back into the codebehind from javascript (using a WebMethod, or equivalent), but apparently you can't call code that isn't static, which would mean I couldn't modify the page itself, or for that matter, access the session or page state. StackOverflow is also full of questions about how to have javascript request that an UpdatePanel refresh itself (__doPostBack()), but without any way to communicate to the server what was clicked on, the UpdatePanel wouldn't know what to display.

Thus, the question, which I'm hoping has an answer: am I missing some clever way to have javascript on the page trigger a server-side function capable of taking a parameter and using it to do a partial postback of a different UpdatePanel?

Thanks!

Comment: For anyone else who happens to stumble on this question: I couldn't get the below answer to work, so I just completely side-stepped the issue, by instead of ajax-ly information on the *same* page, instead using a lightbox plugin to open a *new* page in a bubble with the information I wanted to display on clicking. That worked great and fulfilled all the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite straightforward. Just place a LinkButton inside of second update panel (it can have an empty text and thus be invisible), in JavaScript call client-side `.click()` method of that control, and in ASP.NET handle server-side `OnClick` event.